# 3D アニメーション

Tags: css, scss

YouTubeのtutorialビデオ https://youtube.com/watch?v=NSWr6dkc_Xw&t=418s を見て　そっくりそのままコピーしながら3Dアニメーションを作ろうとしています。
ある所まで順調にできました。そこまで出来上がったhtmlとscssが下記の通りです。
html

```html
<div class="banner">
       <div class="panel"></div>
       <div class="panel"></div>
       <div class="panel"></div>
       <div class="panel"></div>
       <div class="panel"></div>
       <div class="panel"></div>
       <div class="panel"></div>
       <div class="panel"></div>
       <div class="panel"></div>
       <div class="panel"></div>
       <div class="panel"></div>
       <div class="panel"></div>
       <div class="panel"></div>
       <div class="panel"></div>
       <div class="panel"></div>
       <div class="panel"></div>
       <div class="panel"></div>
       <div class="panel"></div>
       <div class="panel"></div>
       <div class="panel"></div>
       <div class="panel"></div>
       <div class="panel"></div>
       <div class="panel"></div>
       <div class="panel"></div>
   </div>
```

scss

```
body {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
  
}

.banner {
    display: flex;
}
$width: 23px;
.panel {
    position: relative;
    width: $width;
    height: 110px;
  // border: 1px solid white;
   overflow: hidden;
   animation: rotate 6s infinite ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    from { transform: rotateX(0deg); }
    to { transform: rotateX(360deg);}
}

.panel::before {
    position: absolute;
    left: var(--left);
    content: 'Hello World';
    font-size: 96px;
    width: max-content;
    color: hsl(var(--hue), 75%, 75%);
}

@for $i from 0 to 24 {
    .panel:nth-child(#{$i + 1}) {
        --left: #{$width * $i * -1};
        --hue: #{360 / 24 * $i};
}
}
```

ここからビデオの16:00あたりではbodyの最終に

```
perspective: 500px;
```

と書き入れると平面的だったのが立体的になりますが、私が書いたのでは何も変化が起きません。

Windows10を使っています。モニターに映す時chrome,edge,firefoxのどれでやっても何も変化しません。
どこが悪いのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

`.banner` に `transform-style: preserve-3d;` を追加してください。

```scss
.banner {
  display: flex;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

`perspective` を効かせるためには `preserve-3d` を使って 3D レンダリング・コンテキストを作る必要があります。

https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/transform-style

> `transform-style` は CSS のプロパティで、要素の子要素を 3D 空間に配置するのか、平面化して要素の平面に配置するのかを設定します。

https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-2/#3d-rendering-contexts

> A 3D rendering context is established by a transformable element whose used value for `transform-style` is `preserve-3d` and which itself is not part of a 3D rendering context. An element that establishes a 3D rendering context also participates in that context.

元の動画で参照されている完成品 https://codepen.io/kevinpowell/pen/abwqBxE でも現在は上手く動いていませんし、ちゃんと調べてはいませんが、動画公開時とブラウザの挙動が変わっていそうです。